# Is there a way to do a loop in the select part of a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am returning CommissionDocuments for a user. The CommissionDocument contains many policies that the user gets commission for.

So I want to sum up the commission for each policy in the CommissionDocument.

I've tried using the Sum() method that didn't work.

Query

```
    public async Task<List<Commission>> FetchAsync(Agent agent)
    {
      return await _agentsContext.ScanCommDoc
        .Include(x => x.CommissionStatement)
        .Where(x => x.AgentId == agent.AgentId && x.Type == FileType.CommissionStatement
           && x.CommissionStatement.PaymentYear == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Year
           && x.CommissionStatement.PaymentMonth == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Month)
           .Select(x => new AgentCommission { ScanDate = x.ScanDate, FileUrl = x.FileUrl Commission = (x.AgentCommission .Amount + x.AgentCommission .Vat) })
           .GroupBy(x => x.ScanDate).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Take(2)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.ScanDate).ToListAsync();
```

Agent Commission(DB Table)

```
public class AgentCommissionStatement
  {
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }

    public Byte PaymentMonth { get; set; }

    public Int16 PaymentYear { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
  }
```

Commission Mapping Class

```
  public class AgentCommission
  {
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
    public Guid? FileGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Commission { get; set; }
  }
```

```
 public class ScanCommDoc
  {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AgentId { get; set; }

    public string FileUrl { get; set; }

    public Guid? FileGuid { get; set; }

    public PolicyDetail Policy { get; set; }

    public FileType Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }

    public CommissionStatement CommissionStatement { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: so you tried doing .ToList().
Select(x=>x.table.Amount).sum()?

Comment: I don't see any use of `Sum()` in your code, but you're missing a comma after `FileUrl = x.FileUrl `.

Comment: @terrencep not sure where in the query you're referring to. Can you use the above code please.

Comment: @Henrik I did try to use it after the select on AgentCommission  object. The comma was just a typo while including the code in my question.

Comment: Can you make sure your code compiles, and perhaps add a comment showing what you would like to `Sum`? Also, you refer to "policy" but I see no policy objects in the code.

Comment: @NetMage I've posted the answer below. The commission is for a policy, unfortunately it would have been out of the scope of my question to include the policy object as I just wanted to get the total sum of the commission.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help and suggestions. 
Below is what I was trying to do.
I was able to get the sum of the commission.

```
public async Task<List<Commission>> FetchAsync(Agent agent)
    {
        return await _agentsContext.ScanCommDoc
          .Include(x => x.CommissionStatement)
          .Where(x => x.AgentId == agent.AgentId && x.Type == FileType.CommissionStatement
             && x.CommissionStatement.PaymentYear == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Year
             && x.CommissionStatement.PaymentMonth == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Month)
             .Select(x => new { x.ScanDate, x.FileUrl, x.FileGuid,  commission = (x.CommissionStatement.Amount + x.CommissionStatement.Vat) })
             .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileGuid, x.FileUrl, x.ScanDate })
                     .Select(p => new AgentCommission
                     {
                         FileGuid = p.Key.FileGuid,
                         FileUrl = p.Key.FileUrl,
                         ScanDate = p.Key.ScanDate,
                         Commission = p.Sum(x => x.commission)
                     })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.ScanDate).Take(10).ToListAsync();
    }
```